# Java Custom enum

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I have a table and want to save the status using a enum. I created a enum as below

```
/**
 * Enumeration for Status
 * 
 * 
 * Current defined values are :
 * <ul>
 *  <li>ACTIVE = 1</li>
 *  <li>INACTIVE = 2</li>
 * </ul>
 */
public enum Status {

    /**
     * ACTIVE (Ordinal 1).
     */
    ACTIVE(1),

    /**
     * INACTIVE (Ordinal 2).
     */
    INACTIVE(2),



    private int value;

    private Status(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }



   public static void main (String ars[]){
       for (Status str : Status.values()) {
           System.out.println("====str==========="+str.name() +"::::::: "+str.ordinal());
       }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


}
```

How to I get the ordinal value from 1. My output is like this

```
====str===========ACTIVE::::::: 0
====str===========INACTIVE::::::: 1
```

Actually i have mapped this enum to my Entity and i have used it as below

```
@Column(name = "STATUS",nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Status status;
```

How to i save the Active status as 1 ... ?

Comment: **An `enum` should never be mutable.** You should never have a `setXXX` method on an `enum` and an `enum` should **never** have non-`final` variables. Having a mutable `enum` violates many of the guarantees provided by `enum`.

Answer (score 5):

You could override the toString() method of your enum or provide a getter.

```
public enum Status {

    /**
     * ACTIVE (Ordinal 1).
     */
    ACTIVE(1),

    /**
     * INACTIVE (Ordinal 2).
     */
    INACTIVE(2); // Note the semicolon



    private final int value;

    private Status(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // OR
    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

Then you can call

```
System.out.println(ACTIVE); // toString is called
```

or

```
System.out.println(ACTIVE.getValue());
```

Comment: Actually i have mapped this enum to my Entity and i have used it as below

Answer (score 1):

Use `getValue()` instead of `ordinal()`? `ordinal()` doesn't magically know to call your method, it just returns the ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

print `str.getValue()`.

ordinal gives you default values.